# `svn checkout` fails with the “cannot run program” “cannot find the file specified” error

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I'm Checking a sample in google code. It requested me to checkout the source using SVN Checkout. Sine I am using Android Studio, I used the Subversion checkout options in VCS-->Checkout from version control-->Subversion. Howerver I encountered an error. Is their something I have done wrong?

Checking out google sourcecode.

[image: Checkout Google Code]

Error = 2

[image: Error Cannot Find File Specified.]

As you can see in this, picture you can see the folders and of course the sources but how come it could not find it?

[image: As you can see in this picture, you can see the folders of the sources.]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The error `Cannot load supported formats: Cannot run program "svn": Create process error=2, The system cannot find the file specified` indicates that Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA can't locate Subversion 1.8 command-line client on your machine. Follow these steps to solve the issue:

1. Make sure that you use the latest version of Android Studio IDE.
2. Make sure that command-line svn.exe 1.8 client is installed on your system. You can get one at http://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/
3. Add the command-line client to %PATH% environment variable.
4. Restart Android Studio.

You may want to read the related blog post about the same issue with IntelliJ IDEA: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/subversion-1-8-and-intellij-idea-13/

Comment: A very precise answer. The fault was, android studio has no svn build on it. After doing your steps, I can now checked out the sources.

Comment: make sure u restart Android Studio after this change to avoid 3 minutes of confusion :)

Comment: Superb saved a lots of time of mine

Comment: If you are installing Tortoise SVN, make sure you check the option Command Line tools while installation, else you continue getting the same error.

Answer (score 18):

None of the answers here were working for me, though they were on the right track. This was the solution for me:

- Download SVN command line tool from http://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/ as bahrep mentioned.  Stick the binaries somewhere.
- In IDEA: File > Settings > Version Control > Subversion > And then...
- Make sure "Use command line client" is checked and select the path of your SVN.EXE.

By default, the path was simply set as `svn`.  I had to change it to `c:\wherever\i\put\it\svn.exe`

Comment: I actually looked for 'And then...' for about a minute until I realized what you ment :) - Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: now(2021, Android Studio 4.1.3), there is no option `Use command line client`. just set the path to `SVN.EXE`

Answer (score 17):

I am not sure if accepted answers works. But Android Studio-> Settings->Subversion-> Uncheck  "Use command-line client" worked for me!
[image]

Comment: This approach is VERY bad. Don't use the built-in client when you can use svn.exe

Comment: Not a good answer. Ensure you had the command line client installed. If not download it on https://subversion.apache.org/download.cgi and set the path of the svn.exe in command line client parameter.

Comment: in mycase I uncheck both check box. This only works for me

Answer (score 8):

I Have Android studio version 0.8.14
Here is What I have done

Go to settings-> (Preference in Mac)->subversion->
in general tab **uncheck** the three box :

1. User Command Line Client
2. Use system default blalbala
3. Update Administrative blabla

And go to Network Tab : 
select SSL Protocol to : SSLv3

Hope it Works. mine working like a charm.

Comment: 1+ because that's the only one that works for mac osx user. i hope other user upvote this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've got Android Studio v1.4.1 and...

1. Check that the SVN plug in is present and activated.  (/File/Settings, *Subversion Integration* should be in the list.
2. / File/ Settings/ Version Control/ Subversion/ Uncheck *use command line client*
3. Test communicating with the repository via / VCS / Browse VCS Repository / Browse Subversion Repository.  The *SVN Repositories* window should appear and you can add your repository there and see what is inside that repository.

By default *Use command line client* is checked but you can change that with / File / Other Settings / Default Settings / etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way for fixing this error, if you are on a Windows platform would be installing SVN directly from this download source http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

This runs an installer that automatically creates directories, and registers SVN routes for future command line use.

Answer (score 0):

Follow easy steps:

Download Apache Subversion command line tools from below url

https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/

extract the folder and save to some location and copy the path of folder
now in android studio

Android Studio-> File->Other Settings->Default Setting->version control

now here
only check use command line client and paste the above folder path.

now you can give path of sub version.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable interactive mode by clicking on checkbox in front of "Enable Interactive Mode" under File=>Settings=>Version Control=>Subversion apart from setting "Path to Subversive executable" as suggested in other post.