# Compiling project takes 30~ mins when project on network drive

Tags: gradle, android-studio

As the title explains, I've just moved my project onto works network drive so if my PC blows up I don't lose the work, but when I press run Gradle takes around 30 mins to build. Is there anyway I can debug why it is taking so long to try and figure out how to speed this up?

Update: Looking at the Gradle console, it seems to be stuck on `:actionbarsherlock:processReleaseResources` for quite a while.

Comment: If you don't want to lose your work, why don't you use a SCM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup a small version control system (VCS), which does not need a server (like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)).

Keep a master repository on your network drive and a local clone on your PC. Push your changes back to the master repository often and enjoy the benefits of securing your code and managing its changes in history.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried setting it up via SVN, but I get an error checking out the project, and IT doesn't seem to want to install me svn so until I find a way around network drive seems to be my next best option

Comment: @TomHart Surely IT provides some form of version control software or at least a backup so the company does not lose data

Comment: We have a svn repo setup for websites, which works fine on our VPS server, but my local machine throws the error `Cannot load supported formats: Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified` when trying to checkout a project from the repo. I'll have a dig around see if I can see what the error means exactly.

Comment: Look into Git or Mercurial. They are not server - client oriented. They can be used privately by you only without needing any IT support.

Comment: @TomHart - Do you have a subversion client installed. Try getting it  from http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/  Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677210/android-studio-0-5-2-svn-checkout-not-working